# pushing to array when recieving value from Knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, es6-promise, knex.js

i am building a twitter like app. my Node server retrieves data from the sql database using knex.
i have an issue with the code at the endpoint that's supposed to get the posts ('emails' is an array):

```
app.post('/posts', (req, res) => {
    const { emails } = req.body;

    let arr = [];

    emails.forEach(email => {
        db('*')
        .from('posts')
        .where('email', '=', email)
            .then(result => {
                arr.push(result)
            })
    })

    res.json(arr)
})
```

when i console log the 'result' inside the promise i'm getting the desired post, but i get an empty array at the response. 
i'm assuming the problem has somewhat to do with the fact that it's a promise?
i've tried to somehow turn this into a async function but didn't succeed in making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every one of those `db` calls return a promise, which you currently ignore. And because you're not waiting for them, your `res.json` call runs before the `arr.push` calls.

1. I changed `forEach` to `map`
2. I returned the promises from the `db` calls, so now I have an array of promises.
3. I waited for all those promises with `Promise.all`
4. Its `then` will get the results of all those promises in an array, so no need for the `arr` array anymore.
5. Then I can send the response.

Code:

```
Promise.all(
  emails.map(
    email => db("*").from("posts").where("email", "=", email)
  )
).then(results => {
  res.json(results);
});
```

Comment: thanks! i just posted my solution about the same time you did, so almost missed it, but looks much better and makes a lot of sense